# Playback an array of audio files in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm working on an app where I want to play a series of short audio clips, mostly words of very short sentences. (spoken instructions) And play them one after another.

I have created an init function where I load the audios into a `AVAudioPlayer`, prepair it for playing and append it to an array for later use.

```
func initAudioFiles () {
    for audioFile in self.audioFiles {
        let urlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: audioFile, ofType: "mp3")!
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlPath)
        do {
            let avAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: fileURL)
            avAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            self.avAudioPlayers.append(avAudioPlayer)
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Later, I want to play back a series of audio's for example 
`'hello', 'your timer is set to', '1', 'minute', 'and', '1', 'hour'`. 
Note that an `AVQueuePlayer` is not going to work due to the fact that there is chance two of the same audios are queued.

So I created the following script to play them one after another.

```
for avAudioPlayerIndex in avAudioPlayerIndexes {
    let avAudioPlayer = self.avAudioPlayers[avAudioPlayerIndex]

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(currentDeadline)) {
        avAudioPlayer.play()
        print("playing \(avAudioPlayer.play)")

        // when the audio is played, reset and prepare it!
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(Int(avAudioPlayer.duration * 1000)) + .seconds(1)) {
            avAudioPlayer.currentTime = 0
            avAudioPlayer.pause()
            avAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        }
    }

    // add its duration to the current deadline counter
    let audioDurationMS = Int (avAudioPlayer.duration * 1000)
    currentDeadline += audioDurationMS
}
```

An Dispatch queue is created where all the audio's are queued after the last ones duration. When I print all the queued times, they are at least a second apart from each other. But when running the code, the "Playing..." `print` for each audio file a very off. Especially when a previous played sound is repeated, some audio files are played at the same time. This always happens the same way.

Any solution? Could this be occurred by the DispatchQueue, or by the audio playback being  laggy? Is anyone experiencing the same problems? Or is there a better way of approaching this?

Thanks in advance!